# JavaScript jQuery: Table rows are not drag/dropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the JavaScript portion that I have that *should* make the table's rows that I have drag and droppable (aka movable). This doesn't work for some reason.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){ jQuery("#sortable93032188").sortable({ items: "tr:.sortable" }); })
</script>
```

Here's the table info:

```
<table id="sortable93032188" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="0" leftmargin="50">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="vdarkbluebw" valign="centre">
                    <font>Field Order - Drag fields up or down as required to preferred order</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#eeeee8" class="sortable" id="11874272">
                <td id="68937878">
                    <span class="small">Sample Origin Name<input type="hidden" name="new_field_order" value="Sample Origin Name"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
... This table keeps going (it's decently sized).
```

Now the thing is that I've googled around on drag/drop tables -- and I can't seem to find what's wrong with this. I have very little jQuery/HTML/JavaScript experience and am stumped at this point. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry that's just a typo. Let me fix that.

Comment: is the table being generated dynamically?? If so you have to make sure that the sortable function in the jQuery is called AFTER the table is added to the DOM

Comment: Table is generated dynamically but that part is done with the perl scripts in the back end. So from the pov of the html page it's not really. So that I would think wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take out the semicolon in your jQuery after the `tr`.

```
jQuery(function(){ jQuery("#sortable93032188").sortable({ items: "tr.sortable" }); })
```

It should work then. Heres a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7kZY4/

Comment: It's not working for me. :(  Hmm... the javascript function is *right* above the HTML table code. Do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: @Joe in the fiddle or on your page?

Comment: @Joe what jQuery are you using you have to make sure you're including jQuery UI its a different library than the standard jQuery one

Comment: On the actual page. They are inside together in a <span> block. EDIT: I *think* we're using 1.8.17.

Comment: @Joe what are together inside a span block? The tables??

Comment: The table and the script. The script is right above the table code.

Comment: I see but I mean where you include the library not the actual javascript itself. It should be in your header. Should look like this (regular jQuery) but you need the UI version (second link)

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`    UI: 

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Joe the sortable function is only available in the UI version of jQuery check your console and see if you have an errors. You should have one saying sortable isnt supported if you dont have UI included

Comment: Oh the library. The libraries are imported at the top of the page. We have jquery UI 1.8.17 and jQuery 1.10.2 imported.

Comment: Ah, crud. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable' Found that in the console. But I wonder why. I have virtually no experience with web dev.

Comment: That means your jQuery UI isnt being added properly or doesnt support the sortable youre using. After a quick poke at their documentation http://jqueryui.com/changelog/. They have been making tons of updates to sortable. I would strongly suggest just updating you UI version to the latest version

Comment: Updating may be out of option -- this is a small portion of a very large web interface. Can't just update like that. Not sure why it'd be not loaded properly? <script src='/js/jquery-ui-custom.js'></script> is right under the header. It's one of the first things loaded. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Joe ahhh its a custom download of jQuery UI. I would bet that the sortable interaction isn't included in it. Unfortunately I don't think there's much you can do without being able to update or edit that UI file.

Comment: I doubt it though - we had this working in our previous version apparently, and this just... broke in the newest version.

Comment: I went through it and the UI file definitely has sortable in there and we have jQuery v1.10.2 in there as well. No other way you can think of?

Comment: @Joe I have no idea then. The only thing I can think of is that somehow the UI is not being added before you try and call sortable but I dont see how thats possible if its in your header. You did have the one syntax error and once that I fixed that and we checked everything else Im out of ideas. Sorry I couldnt find the answer

Comment: Gahh, found it. You were right there were compatibility issues. We had a number of jQuery things being loaded for some reason and they were causing issues.  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js  This was the one that was causing the problem -- why though I have no idea.

Comment: I convinced my supervisors to let me test after upgrading -- and I ran into another problem. I upgraded jQuery UI to 1.10.3 from the link you gave me, and then used jQuery 1.10.2 (what we have) with it, and it still broke. I also tried using jQuery 1.9.1 which is what that jQuery UI came with, and it still broke. BUT if I use jQuery 1.7.1 (another older version we had), it worked. Any ideas?